# View descriptor not found exception in eclipse PDE

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How can I debug "View descriptor not found" ? I am sure that the view id passed in addView() (called during the perspective's createInitialLayout() method) is really the view id of the
view to which I refer and that view is declared in its plugin. In fact,
it works in my workspace but not in the binary despite the very same
plugins being present in the binary.

Nevertheless, I get "View descriptor not found" (stack trace attached at
end).

Any tips appreciated.

```
    org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException: View descriptor not found: myTree.TreeView
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.FolderLayout.addView(FolderLayout.java:75)
    at com.xxx.yyy.perspective.perspectives.RelEngPerspective.addViews(RelEngPerspective.java:87)
    at com.xxx.yyy.perspective.perspectives.RelEngPerspective.createInitialLayout(RelEngPerspective.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.loadPredefinedPersp(Perspective.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.createPresentation(Perspective.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.<init>(Perspective.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.tweaklets.Workbench3xImplementation.createPerspective(Workbench3xImplementation.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.createPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:1672)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyResetPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:927)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$13(WorkbenchPage.java:876)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$14.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3093)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.resetPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:3091)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ResetPerspectiveAction.run(ResetPerspectiveAction.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveAction.run(PerspectiveAction.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it works in your workspace and not in the binary, there might be a problem in the `build.properties` of the plug-in declaring the view. Please check whether your `plugin.xml` is among the artifacts exported with the plug-in.

Comment: i have checked with jar plugin.xml is available.totally am deploying it as 3 plugins.